# Send message through websocket using javascript

Tags: javascript, websocket

I am connecting to a WebSocket Server using javascript and the Play Framework. I am just having trouble understanding the proper way to make use of the websocket.send() method of the WebSocket.

```
 $(function() {

    //depending on the browser we have to use WebSocket or MozWebSocket
    var WS = window['MozWebSocket'] ? MozWebSocket : WebSocket;
    var websocket = new WS('ws://localhost:9000/webSocket');

    websocket.onopen = function() {
        websocket.send('test');
    }
    //split the message from the websocket into type, user and text
    //uses a nifty regular expression
    websocket.onmessage = function (event) {
        $('.output').append(event.data);
    }
});
```

When I use `send()` outside the `onopen` event I get an error because `send()` is not available. I am just thinking that there must be another event to dynamically execute `send()` without the `onopen` event which (afaik) just executes when the connection opens up.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onopen` is the correct event handler to use as it is the handler that is used when the connection is ready to be used.

the api docs show only 4 event handlers
`onopen`
`onmessage`
`onerror`
`onclose`

[Api doc](http://dev.w3.org/html5/websockets/#the-websocket-interface)